# Type Mismatch error: Don't Understand Why

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I am trying to add one value to another, but it always stops somewhere in my code and throws:

> Error Type 13: Mismatch Error

even when removing one part of the code another error appears with the same error. For example:

When this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 9) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 42)
```

The first error, appeared, I wanted to troubleshoot it by erasing it and the same error would appear on this:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 6) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 41)
```

The Whole Code:

```
Do While (j < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 9)) + 3)


For i = 7 To 65

'Megaform

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 6) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 41)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 7) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 7) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 44)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 8) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 8) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 47)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 9) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 9) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 42)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 10) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 10) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 45)
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 11) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 11) + Sheets(j).Cells(i, 48)

Next i
```

Comment: One of the cells is either a text or error, neither can be added to a number.

Comment: When it errors, click debug and look at what the values are for the two cells you are trying to add together. There's nothing wrong with your code, the problem is in the data it's processing.

Comment: I just checked, they are all good, I even changed the cells to Numbers, in case that would have been the problem. Another weird thing is that it takes a number that is not mentioned

Comment: break into the code and go line by line with F8 checking each value to ensure it is looking at the cell you think it should be.

Comment: @MaxAttack102 "Another weird thing is that it takes a number that is not mentioned" I'm not exactly sure what that means, but take a look at the answer I provided - specifically Danger #2 - that may be what you're running into.

Comment: I've checked everything there is nothing

Comment: That `J` loop looks very wrong BTW. It's literally asking for an out-of-bounds error to happen, and if the workbook structure isn't protected then your user is 1 accidental drag/drop from wrecking everything (e.g. by moving a sheet before index 3). J should be based on worksheet collection count, not some cell's value. Also the `+` operator will be making implicit type conversions. Make them explicit with `CDbl` or whatever is appropriate, and always check for `IsError` before you do anything with a cell value, otherwise you get the error you're getting.

Comment: I forgot to add the j, but it is referenced

Comment: @Mat'sMug - You beat me to it, though I didn't see your comment before updating my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As was mentioned in the comments on your OP, you've got text or an error in the cells you're trying to add. You may have a number stored as text so it *looks* like a number when you see it in the cell, but Excel (& VBA) will treat it as text. If that's the case `CInt(ThisWorkbook...)` around each cell reference will convert it. But it won't convert `Some text` or `#ERROR` to an integer for you. You may want to create a bit of validation code around each line, something like this:

```
Sub temp()
  Const NAN   As String = "Non-number in source data"

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
    Dim J     As Long
    Do While (J < (.Cells(1, 9)) + 3)
      Dim OtherWorksheet As Worksheet
      Set OtherWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J)

      Dim i   As Long
      For i = 7 To 65
        'Megaform
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 6)) And IsNumeric(Sheets(J).Cells(i, 41)) Then
          .Cells(i, 6) = .Cells(i, 6) + Sheets(J).Cells(i, 41)
        Else
          .Cells(i, 6) = NAN
        End If
        If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 7)) And IsNumeric(OtherWorksheet.Cells(i, 44)) Then
          .Cells(i, 7) = .Cells(i, 7) + OtherWorksheet.Cells(i, 44)
        Else
          .Cells(i, 7) = NAN
        End If

        'etc...

      Next
      'I hope there's some incrementer for J down here!!
    Loop
  End With

End Sub
```

A couple of notes on the code:

- I declared `NAN` as a constant string to insert when there is invalid input data
- I added a `With` block so I didn't have to type `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)` dozens of times

  - This means that every range reference that starts with `.` refers back to this to pick up the full reference
- **Danger #1** the unqualified `Sheets(3)` reference in the *FIRST* `If` statement refers to the *currently* active workbook. Your `'Megaform` comment leads me to believe that this could be a long running process. That could lead to your user clicking on another workbook. If that happens, `Sheets()` now refers to the workbook he just selected, not the one you were working with.

  - I resolved that in the *SECOND* `If` statement by setting `OtherWorksheet` to be sheet #J in `ThisWorkbook` immediately after the start of the `Do While` loop. `ThisWorkbook` *always* refers to the workbook the code is running in, so even if the user switches books on you, you can still get back to where you were. The 2nd `If` statement then uses a fully qualified `OtherWorksheet.` notation to ensure it's reading from the correct worksheet.
- **Danger #2** the `Sheets()` collection includes all sheet types in a workbook. This includes `Chart` sheets. `Chart` sheets won't work they way you're expecting them to here, so if someone happens to insert a Chart sheet in your workbook, your code will blow up (run-time error) when `J` points to it. By using the `Worksheets()` collection, you avoid that potential issue.
- I added some proper indentation to the code since that makes the code structure much easier to identify with a quick scan. I used [Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/)<sup>*</sup> to do that for me. It also has a code inspection feature that will provide *many* suggestions on other improvements you can make to your code.
- You don't show your declaration for `J`or any initialization or incrementer for it, so I hope those are there. It may make for a more simple loop to use
  `For J = StartValue to .Cells(1,9) + 3`
  I tend to prefer a `For` loop when the end points are definable, but there's no requirement to do so.
- I didn't write the `If` protection around all your addition statements. I figured this was a good example and you can copy/paste the rest.

<sup>*</sup>Rubberduck is an open source project (available on GitHub) working hard to bring the VBE into the 21st century. My involvement is as a satisfied user and semi-pro <s>complainer</s> tester.

---

**To address the `Subscript out of range` error:**

You'll note that in the bullet points I did point out that I saw nothing in your original code that set `J` to begin with. If there was nothing, it would start at `0` which is out of range for the `WorkSheet` collection (it's 1-based). I also called out a suggestion to insure that there was something in there to increment it.

My presumption was that `Thisworkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1,9)` contained the number (minus 3, for some reason) of worksheets you want to process. It sounds now like you're trying to use it to keep track of the number of `WorkSheets` in your `WorkBook` which is unnecessary and fraught with error.

If you're trying to process *all* the `WorkSheets` in the `WorkBook` (except for `Worksheets(2)` which is where the data will end up, I presume), replace:

```
Dim J as Long
Do While (J < (.Cells(1, 9)) + 3)
  Dim OtherWorksheet As Worksheet
  Set OtherWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(J)
  .
  .
  .
Loop
```

With this code instead:

```
Dim CurrentSheet as WorkSheet
For Each CurrentSheet in ThisWorkbook
  If CurrentSheet.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Name Then
    .
    'the existing code here.
    'NOTE: references to OtherWorksheet need to be changed to CurrentSheet
    '      Or, change "CurrentSheet" to "OtherWorksheet" in three places here, whichever is easier
    .
Next
```

This will process through all the `WorkSheets` in your `WorkBook`, skipping `WorkSheet(2)` which it identifies by name. If there are other worksheets that you need to skip, you can add them to the `If` statement with an `And` in between (i.e. don't process if `.Name = "Fred" And .Name = "Barney"`)

Comment: You beat me to it and in style!

Comment: Another error is appearing : **Subscript out of Range** . When click debug it says it's on `Set OtherWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j)`

Comment: Initialize J to 1 outside the do while

Comment: @RIBH Thank you, but my number is still showing the wrong  place. but I guess that's inside the worksheet's temselves

Comment: @MaxAttack102 A lot depends on what's in cell Sheets(2).Cells(1,9) and how many sheets are there in your workbook and what number appears where you don't want it too. Can't help more without understanding really what's the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @MaxAttack102 - I've added an additional suggestion for the loop that may work much better for you - or, it may not. I don't know the structure of your workbook.

Comment: @RIBH - Thanks! I've been hanging out a [Codereview.se], so I've started getting in the habit of a bit of review with a fix. May as well _try_ to get newbies into some good coding habits since VBA religiously promotes such _bad_ habits.

Comment: @FreeMan - Good habit. I usually try to retain the structure from OPs. Less assumptions mean better chances of a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is in-fact the case but still sharing my hypothesis. I believe that when you run this macro, another workbook is open. When you refer to `Sheets()` in your code without referring to any workbook, Excel picks up the sheet from the book that's active. This may not be what you want if the second book is active.

To get around this, you need to explicitly mention the workbook you want to use as source. I have modified your code to do this:

```
Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
Dim DestinationSheet As Worksheet

Set DestinationSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

j = 1

Do While (j < (ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(1, 9)) + 3)

    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(j)

    For i = 7 To 65

        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 6) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 6) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 41)
        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 7) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 7) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 44)
        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 8) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 8) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 47)
        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 9) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 9) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 42)
        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 10) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 10) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 45)
        DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 11) = DestinationSheet.Cells(i, 11) + SourceSheet.Cells(i, 48)

    Next i

    j = j + 1

Loop
```

Comment: It read that workbook, it just read the first sheeet and the second would give an error like this

Comment: Just saw that I had missed incrementing j. Modified the code now.

Comment: With this code, there _will_ be a point (when `J=2`) where `DestinationSheet = SourceSheet` is `True`, and you'll get `DestinationSheet` info added into itself. Don't know if that's desired or not, but something to be aware of.

Comment: Agreed. J = 1 is a poor assumption. It has to be initialized though and without further information about the workbook/sheet structure, this question is going to be impossible to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2).Cells(i, 9)
```

Rename your sheet to Say "Sheet1"

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 9)
```